# Non standard syntax - Use & to create a pointer to a member : C++ function pointer to member

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am creating a spirograph application, and have a simple GUI class, which produces and manages buttons - you can call this functions with a custom function pointer upon clicking on them.

I also have an Engine class, which manages the drawing of my spirograph, and the GUI buttons.

I would like to create a button that has a pointer to a member function from within the engine class, but I keep getting an error.

The error is coming when I try to create a button with a function pointer from the Engine class.

Here is the problem in a nutshell, as suggested by Frank in the comments (thank you)

```
    class Engine;
typedef void(Engine::*enginefunc)(void);

class Engine
{
    void cb();
    void register_callback(enginefunc ptr);

    void foo() {
        register_callback(cb);
    }
};
```

Here is my engine class:

Engine.h

```
class Engine : public GUI
{
private:
//....
public:
    Engine(sf::Vector2f* mousepos);
    //...
//...inherited a function from GUI called addbutton.

};
Engine::Engine(sf::Vector2f* mousepos)
    :GUI(mousepos)
{   


//THIS IS THE LINE WHICH PRODUCES THE ERROR. I AM TRYING TO PASS THE CHANGE POINT FUNCTION INTO THE GUI BUTTON.
        addbutton(sf::Vector2f{ 100,50 }, sf::Vector2f{ 200,100 }, "Button", sf::Color::Red, sf::Color::Blue, changepoint); 
    }
```

Here is the GUI.h (Contains the addbutton function which is causing the error)

```
class Engine;

typedef void(Engine::* enginefunc)(void);

class GUI : public sf::Drawable
{
private:    
    //...
public:

    GUI(sf::Vector2f* mousepos);
    void addbutton(const sf::Vector2f& position, const sf::Vector2f& dimension, const std::string& text, sf::Color initcolor, sf::Color highlightcolor, enginefunc ptr);
    //other member funcs..
};
```

Here is the GUI::addbutton function

```
void GUI::addbutton(const sf::Vector2f& pos, const sf::Vector2f& size, const std::string& text, sf::Color before, sf::Color after, enginefunc ptr)
{
    buttons.emplace_back(pos, size, text, before, after, ptr);
}
```

So the addbutton function creates a GUIButton class, which stores the function ptr. When the button is clicked, that function pointer is called via std::invoke.

Here is my GUIButton.h

```
class Engine;
typedef void(Engine::*enginefunc)(void);
class GUIButton :  public sf::RectangleShape
{
public:
    GUIButton(const sf::Vector2f& position, const sf::Vector2f& size, const std::string& text, sf::Color initcolor, sf::Color highlightcolor, enginefunc ptr);
    void action(Engine& e);
    //other members...
private:
//other members...
    enginefunc actionptr;
};
```

As you can see, the enginefunc GUIButton::actionptr is the function pointer which will be actioned when the button is pressed.

Here is the GUIButton::action() function which calls the function:

```
    void GUIButton::action(Engine& e)
{
    if (actionptr != nullptr)
    {
        std::invoke(actionptr, e);
    }
}
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I understand that a pointer to member function must be tied to a specific object, which is why I have taken in the Engine object as reference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Putting aside how to fix your code for a second, if you just used a `std::function` instead, it would be a lot easier to code, a lot easier to read, and a lot more flexible.

Comment: Also: Can I suggest a MCVE? I think this is basically 100% equivalent to the issue you are facing, correct? https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bj49x5

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your comment. I am a beginner in C++. What is MCVE and what is the purpose of this virtual compiler that you have linked?

Comment: Also, would it be more sensible to almost always use std::function instead of raw function pointers?

Comment: regarding MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Working on MCVE

Comment: And as far as `std::function`. There are a few edge cases where `std::function` falters a bit. Them being: when dealing with movable-only types, and when you need to shave nanoseconds from your program. The first one will just cause a compile error, so don;t worry about it. The second one only happens in extreme circumstances. So yes, `std::function` almost all the time.

Comment: How about now? Changed it.

Comment: Okay, I am going to implement a std::function now.

Comment: Are you happy that the godbolt link correctly reproduces your issue?

Comment: The error message is saying exactly what's wrong. To create a pointer to a member function, you need to say `&`, as in `&Engine::changepoint`.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use a `std::function` instead. In this case, best practices here would call for using a lambda to bind `this`.

The equivalent of your code:

```
class Engine;
typedef void(Engine::*enginefunc)(void);

class Engine
{
    Engine();
    void changepoint();
    void addbutton(enginefunc ptr);
};

Engine::Engine() {
    addbutton(changepoint);
}
```

Becomes:

```
class Engine
{
    Engine();
    void changepoint();
    void addbutton(std::function<void()> ptr);
};

Engine::Engine() {
    addbutton([this](){changepoint();});
}
```